# Failing to hide HTML element within OnClick Event

Tags: javascript, html, hidden

I'm struggling to hide a html element for when the user clicks on a particular button. When the user clicks the confirm button, I need to hide the "save draft" button. When I click on the button, nothing happens. Anything obvious?

It appears to work on here, but not within my codebase. I'm not sure why there would be any issue. The html has the correct link to the JavaScript.

I can see that the hidden attribute is being added the the element, however, it isn't actually hiding it. I'm using twig, so I don't know if that's causing issues?

```js
function addCampaignConfirmButton() {
    document.getElementById("save_draft_button").hidden = true;
}
```

```html
<button type="submit" id="confirm_button" class="custom-btn rounded-8 border-0 confirm background-blue f-14 text-white text-center text-decoration-none mx-3" onclick="addCampaignConfirmButton()">Confirm</button>

{% if campaign is empty or campaign.is_draft == 1 %}
 <button type="submit" id="save_draft_button" class="custom-btn d-block rounded-8 save-draft blue-border f-14 bg-white text-blue text-center text-decoration-none mx-3 mb-2 mb-sm-0" onclick="addCampaignSaveDraftButton()">Save Draft</button>
{% endif %}
```

Comment: `addCampaignSaveDraftButton` != `addCampaignConfirmButton`. Either you have a typo or you've posted wrong `JS` function

Answer (score 0):

Simple you can use this code.

```
var toggle  = document.getElementById("toggle");
var content = document.getElementById("content");

toggle.addEventListener("click", function() {
  content.classList.toggle("show");
});
```

And if you want to use the function in this program, you can use this code.

```
<div id="myDIV" onclick="javascript:myFunction()">myDiv</div>
<script>
function myFunction() {
  var x = document.getElementById('myDIV');
  if (x.style.display === 'none') {
    x.style.display = 'block';
  } else {
    x.style.display = 'none';
  }
}
</script>
```

Hope, You found solution!

Answer (score -1):

Maybe you can use classlist and toogle? Or defined bool variable and checking state afrer click ?

Comment: It's weird because I can see the hidden attribute has been added. I'm using twig so I don't know if maybe that's causing the issues. I'll need to check that out

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).